# Fody: Could not find a weaver named 'PropertyChanged'

Tags: xamarin

I'm working on a `Xamarin` project, and up until Friday, builds worked perfectly. Now, when I try to build for iOS or Android, I'm getting this error

> "Could not find a weaver named 'PropertyChanged'"

. I've tried deleting my local repo and re-cloning, reinstalling `Xamarin`, clearing the .nuget file, making sure my Fody version (1.29.4) is compatible with `PropertyChanged.Fody (1.52.1)`, and making sure the `FodyWeavers.xml` file is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your Fody version? Usually I install only PropertyChanged.Fody Nuget

Comment: Fody version is 1.29.4

Comment: I am saying that I don't installa Fody, I install only PropertyChanged.Fody. BTW I think it's not the problem. Seems like this old issue https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/90

Comment: I tried the solution in the link you provided- had no effect. Also tried removing Fody and keeping PropertyChanged.Fody. Same issue.

Comment: If you clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: In my solution I have Fody and PropertyChanged.Fody. Fody is installed because I install PropertyChanged.Fody. Try to remove also PropertyChanged.Fody and install only it https://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/

Comment: Removed both Fody and PropertyChanged.Fody. Installed just PropertyChanged.Fody, cleaned, and rebuilt. Issue persists.

Comment: FodyWeavers.xml is correct?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
 <PropertyChanged />
</Weavers>`

Comment: After "PropertyChanged" there is a space? try to remove it... maybe... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <PropertyChanged/>
</Weavers>

Comment: removed space, cleaned and rebuilt. Same issue

Comment: I have not other idea... sorry. Have you a little repo that you can post on github so I can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Fixed by adding PropertyChanged.Fody to the Droid project's Packages folder.